# Android Leaderboards - How to disable option for "Today", "This Week" and "All Time"

Tags: android, leaderboard

I have built an incremental leaderboard as specified [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232366/how-to-increment-player-score-in-leaderboards-on-android-google-play-service)

Problem is that android leaderboard shows options for "Today", "This Week" and "All Time". Since my leaderboard is incremental, it doesn't make any sense for me to have these options and hence I want to disable them.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.